# QT, Write in new line in a file

Tags: c++, qt

I have written a code to read from line_Edit in GUI, and write in a file. The code reads the text from line edit and writes the same in the file, but they are printed continuously without any spaces, I want to print the texts written in the line edit in different lines. The file has written text, just want to replace first word of each line by the user entered words.

Code to write in the file:

```
void MainWindow::on_write_btn_clicked(){
    QString str, str2, lin;
    str = ui->lineEdit->text();
    str2 = ui->lineEdit2->text();
    QFile file1("sample.txt");
    if(file1.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text)){
        QTextStream out(&file1);
        out << str;
        lin = out.readLine();
        out << str2;
        file1.seek(30);
        file1.close();
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

File in which we want to write:
[image: file in which we want to write]

Comment: Please write the code as code instead of screenshot.

Comment: I'd like to help, but firewalls are blocking access to your sites.  Please **edit** your post with the **text** of your program.

Comment: Open the file using `QIODevice::Append`, append a `'\n'` followed by your data

Comment: Is the problem fixed? or you need additional assistance?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the next string to be in a new line in the file you should add the new line character(s) to the stream `\n`.
Referring to your code you should put:

```
out << str << '\n' << str2;
```

which would make the contents of `str` and `str2` appear in consecutive lines.

Instead of the above you could also use the `endl` manipulator from `QTextStream`:

```
out << str << endl << str2;
```

For this to work properly you need to be opening the file with `QIODevice::Text` and assure that the `endl` you are specifying actually comes from `QTextStream` (not `std`)
Also note that since you probably only want to write your file there is no need in opening it with `ReadWrite` option, `WriteOnly` should be enough.

**EDIT** according to further details:

To substitute first word from each line of the file you could do the following. Open two files, one which will be read and the second to write the modified data. After iterating though all the lines close the files, remove the original one and rename the output file to replace the original one. Sample implementation:

```
QFile fileIn("textIn.txt"), fileOut("textOut.txt");
fileIn.open(QFile::ReadOnly); // check result
fileOut.open(QFile::WriteOnly); // check result

QTextStream streamIn(&fileIn), streamOut(&fileOut);
const QChar delimeter = ' ';
while (!streamIn.atEnd())
{
    QStringList list = streamIn.readLine().split(delimeter);
    if (list.size() > 0) // in case of empty line
        list[0] = "substitutedText"; // here put the text you want to set
    streamOut << list.join(delimeter) << "\r\n"; // or endl
}
fileIn.close();
fileOut.close();

fileIn.remove(); // check result
fileOut.rename(QFileInfo(fileIn).absoluteFilePath()); // check result
```

Of course you could try doing the replacement on the original file opened with `ReadWrite` modifier and setting proper position inside the stream using `seek`. Although it could get tricky due to different lengths of the read and written data.

Comment: actually `endl` it is equivalent to `'\n'` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#endl

Comment: Thanks for the info, I must have misinterpreted the `note` from documentation. Answer already edited

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried running the code using '\n', the words were printed in next line but the sentence following the word were also shifted to next line. I just wanted to replace 1st word of each line in the file.

Comment: Then maybe I don't fully get what you want to achieve. If you want the text from `lineedit` and `lineedit2` to be put in one line in a file but each time the `on_write_btn_clicked` slot is executed the entry should be put in a separate line, then updating to `out << str << str2 << '\n';` should do the thing

Comment: In the File I want to replace 1st word of the line then read the line, then replace 1st word of 2nd line and read remaining line, and so on. I have used 'ReadWrite' mode but the program is reading the lines first then printing the  words to be replaced at the end of the File.

Comment: So what should the text from both edits be used for? One to replace the first word in each line of the file contens? What about the 'str2'? You should probably update the question since it mostly shows that you have a problem with writing the text to separate lines. Now you write about smth different

Comment: Text from line edits are used to replace the words in the file, str(text of 1st line edit) replaces 1st word of 1st line, str2(text of 2nd line edit) replaces 1st word of 2nd line.

Comment: I got my answer I used flush(), this prints the word then reads the line, then prints 2nd word, else the words were printed only after reading the lines. "if(file1.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream out(&file1);
        out<<str;  out.flush();
        lin = file1.readLine(); 
        out<<str2;
        file1.close();
    }"

Answer (score 0):

Use `\n` instead of `Qt::endl`. `Qt::endl`make flush.

Bench:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QElapsedTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    constexpr const int n = 10000000;
    QElapsedTimer timer1;

    QFile f1("test1.txt");
    f1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QTextStream ts1(&f1);
    timer1.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ts1 << i << "asdfghjkl"
            << i << "qwertyui"
            << i << "1234567890"
            << i << "zxcvbnm"
            << Qt::endl;
    }
    const qint64 elapsed = timer1.elapsed();
    f1.close();

    qDebug() << elapsed;


    QFile f2("test2.txt");
    f2.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QTextStream ts2(&f2);
    QElapsedTimer timer2;
    timer2.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ts2 << i << "asdfghjkl"
            << i << "qwertyui"
            << i << "1234567890"
            << i << "zxcvbnm"
            << '\n';
    }
    const qint64 elapsed2 = timer2.elapsed();
    f2.close();
    qDebug() << elapsed2;

    f1.remove();
    f2.remove();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Results in Debug mode:

`Qt::endl` : 103098

`'\n'` : 16205